# What happens to RAM that is not statically allocated on a microcontroller with FreeRTOS

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, freertos

I'm working on an embedded project with FreeRTOS, where I *only* use static memory allocation.

Looking at my linker script, I find that the following are taking up RAM space:
`.data`
`.bss`
`._user_heap_stack`

To my knowledge, `._user_heap_stack` is used during the linking process to see if there is enough RAM space for the user-specified minimum MSP stack size. Here is a relevant snippet in my linker script:

```
  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM
```

I believe that MSP will always be initialized to point to the end of RAM regardless of `_Min_Stack_Size`, and decrement from there and data is pushed onto the stack. I see that my startup `.S` file configures `sp` as follows:

```
_estack = 0x20004000;    /* end of RAM */

Reset_Handler:
  ldr   sp, =_estack    /* Atollic update: set stack pointer */
```

As for FreeRTOS tasks, they each have stack space that is statically allocated, so it has nothing to do with `_user_heap_stack` I think?

My question is, with the RAM allocated `.data`, `.bss`, and `_user_heap_stack`, I still have some unallocated RAM, so what happens to those RAM? Is it used by anything? Is it ever useful to reserve some free RAM (i.e. non-statically allocated RAM) or is it just wasted? Or perhaps it is just extra space for MSP to use if the main stack ever grows larger in size than what's specified in `_Min_Stack_Size`?

Comment: If you can verify that nothing in your code ever touches it, then nothing in your code ever touches it (though typically it will be zeroed behind the scenes by C startup routines).  One technique sometimes employed is to prefill memory with a magic value (perhaps by modifying the startup code to do that instead of zero), run for a while, and then come back and then see what has changed; the catch is that this only shows the behavior of code paths you actually *exercise*.

Comment: Sometimes guard values are placed *between* used values and checked in the hope of catching overflow, on the theory that it is better to force a restart than run in corrupted state; but again, this only catches things once they trespass, and only if the checker sees it in time.

Comment: Does the magic value method typically assume an active debugger connection? I imagine that you run the code with a debugger, then come back and examine the memory content after a while using the debugger. How would this work if I am deploying the system in the field and don't have an active debugging connection?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on what a guard value is and how it is used? I am not 100% sure what it is, thanks!

Comment: You could build something into the program itself to check (or count) the magic values in un-utilized regions to determine the watermark of maximum utilization so far.  Guard values are the same idea in a smaller range (possibly a single word); you would similarly need to build in a checker or sporadically connect a debugger and look.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! How do these solutions overlap with what an MPU provides? I have limited experience with MPU but to my understanding they restrict RAM access for each RTOS task, so it seems like it's trying to do something similar here?

Comment: An MPU would try to stop things *before* they happen, guard values would try to catch them after, with luck before the issues compound.  But an MPU typically has limited *granularity* so makes more sense on a system with enough memory that you can hand out 4k or so pages like candy and (while the concepts are theoretically independent) tends to go hand in hand with giving each process its own virtual address space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197526/discussion-between-ken-lin-and-chris-stratton).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - The remaining RAM is used by the stack.

---

> Or perhaps it is just extra space for MSP to use if the main stack ever grows larger in size than what's specified in _Min_Stack_Size?

Yes, this seem correct.  See the last paragraph for more; it is not just the stack that is bigger.

See: this part,

```
_estack = 0x20004000;    /* end of RAM */

Reset_Handler:
  ldr   sp, =_estack    /* Atollic update: set stack pointer */
```

So at least the BOOT sp will be at the end of RAM.

The part with `. = . + _Min_Stack_Size;` just makes sure you have a MINIMUM stack or a linker error happens.  Your stack is actually bigger and it is used at least at boot.  I know nothing about FreeRTOS, but I suspect<sup>note1</sup> it is the system stack and you have user stacks.  Each mode on the ARM has a separate stack.  If FreeRTOS has any memory protection or privileged levels, then you will have multiple stacks.  So one task crashing (due to stackoverflow, etc) won't crash the entire system.  Just that tasks<sup>note2</sup> stack is corrupt, and not the one that manages the entire system.

It is a common idiom to have stack and heap together.  With heap growing up and stack growing down.  In this way, the MIN heap size and MIN stack size are imaginary.  Eventually they will collide when the size of both are the total size.  But things maybe okay if the stack goes into heap logical space or heap goes in to stack logical space **AS long as it is not in use by the other**.  By space, I mean the constants in your linker file and not actual in use values.

Note1: It would kind of be insane to both waste memory and have your RTOS code using the same stack as all tasks.  At least it would not be a robust OS.

Note2: By *task* I mean a schedulable entity.  Maybe a process, task, thread, fiber, etc.

Comment: Line 114 or [this file](https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM7_LPC2000/portmacro.h) would indicate they have multiple stacks. `movs pc...` is a mode return instruction which will change the active stack via banked registers. It might depend on the port you use.

Comment: Yep there's definitely one stack per task in FreeRTOS. So I guess the only thing that uses the main stack in main() and ISR? I am wondering if I can adjust this main stack size because my linker is telling me I'm running low on RAM space.

Comment: That file and other routines in it are not only using the 'task' stack, but the system stack.  It look like very little is stored on the system stack.  You didn't give the sizes of min-heap and min-stack.  I couldn't say whether you should change this size.  I guess your 'port' is not in this SVN?  If the linker is complaining, it is because you don't have MIN_HEAP+MIN_STACK left after all the other object code.

Comment: Oh yeah I understand what the linker complaining about. My min heap is 0 because I intend to use no dynamic memory allocation, and my min stack is 1kB out of a total of 16kB RAM

Comment: Have you looked at other ARM ports to see what the value is?  It is just registers and temporaries that seem to be on this stack.  In the 'demo' directory (which should be named BSP or something else).  There is [STR75x crt0.s](https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/FreeRTOS/Demo/ARM7_STR75x_GCC/SystemFiles/crt0_STR75x_FreeRTOS.s) which has 5 stacks define for 608bytes.  In [STR91 IAR init.s](https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/FreeRTOS/Demo/ARM9_STR91X_IAR/91x_init_IAR.s) they load stacks at ~line 135.  You may not use FIQ, depends on the BSP/demo/system.